# Preg Replace with Spaces but only single space

Tags: php, regex

Okay so consider the following string:

`"Hello    How are you??"`

I'd like it to return:

`"Hello_How_are_you"`

But my `preg_replace` is this:

`preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","_",$string);`

Which returns the following:

`"Hello____How are you"`

Whilst good, it gets rid of the foreign characaters but leaves a long line of `___` which looks ugly. I understand why, because it is replacing the spaces with `_` which I what I asked it to do.  However i'd like to to only output the one `_` where it's replaced things.

How can I achiieve this, is it done in the regex or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a quantifier: `+`. `+` means at least one of what was before, grab as many possible:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/","_",$string);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be an alternative regex.

```
$str = "Hello    How are you??";
$op = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $str); // suggested by @Toto

//(or)

$op = preg_replace("/[\s]{1,}/", "_", $str);
```

Comment: Why not using `\s+` that does the same?

Comment: Yes, that is another feasible solution. The part where he specified one or more goes for `+` ofcourse. I'll include your answer too @Toto.